# xf:repeat nodeset poor performance

Tags: xquery, xforms

I fill in a table with xf:repeat nodeset element:

```
           <tbody xf:repeat-nodeset="instance('table')//result">
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xf:output value="interfaceName"></xf:output>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xf:output value="reportDate"></xf:output> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <xf:group ref=".[testResult='success']">
                          <xf:output value="testResult" style="color:green;font-weight:bold"/>
                       </xf:group>
                       <xf:group ref=".[testResult='failure']">
                          <xf:output value="testResult" style="color:red;font-weight:bold"/>
                       </xf:group>
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                            <xf:label>File link</xf:label>
                            <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                                <xf:load show="new">
                                    <xf:resource value="fileLink"/>
                                </xf:load>
                            </xf:action>
                        </xf:trigger>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Iterating over 600 results and filling in 4 columns takes 28 seconds. To my mind, it is way to much. Can anyone suggest how can I improve this?

Comment: I ended up using pagination for the table and restricting number of iterations in this way:

Answer (score 3):

Using // in an XPath expression might be a problem for some XForms engines, at least with XSLTForms, because XForms does not specify how to define an index to improve this. Without an index, all nodes are tested one by one!

You should try with the full path, if possible.

Comment: When I use a full path I don't get anything at all:
tbody xf:repeat-nodeset="instance('table')/results/result"

Comment: I wonder if the root element in your table instance is named 'results'.  If so, remember that the function call "instance('table')" does not return the document node of that instance, but the outermost element.  You may want to write `nodeset = "instance('table')/self::results/result"`.

Answer (score 1):

For read-only display of results like this, I find the `transform()` function supported by some processors very convenient.  Write a stylesheet that accepts your 'result' instance as input and produces an HTML table; I'll call it 'results-to-table.xsl'.  Then write

```
<xf:output value="transform(instance('results'), 
                            'results-to-table.xsl', 
                            false)"
           mediatype="application/xhtml+xml"/>
```

at the appropriate location in your document.

Since `transform()` is not standard in XForms 1.1, this will only work in processors that accept it as an extension to the language; XSLTForms does, but I don't know what other processors do.